# How to interpret null getting returned from SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName?

Tags: ios, reachability

We have this method in our code that returns a `SCNetworkReachabilityRef` using `SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName`:

```
- (SCNetworkReachabilityRef)cCreateReachabilityRefWithCStr:(const char *)host {
    return SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(NULL, host);
}
```

At times we get back NULL for the reachability reference. What does the NULL return mean?

The Apple doc [SCNetworkReachability Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/Reference/reference.html) does not discuss NULL returns from these methods. But the Classes/Reachability.m file in the [Reachability sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) accounts for the fact that `SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName` can return NULL, but without comment as to why.

So what does the NULL return mean and how am I to handle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to a similar query on the iOS Developer Forums [What does a NULL return from SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName mean?](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/185032) (link is only accessible to iOS Developer Program members), someone from Apple Developer Support noted that, as far as he knew, there are only three reasons that `SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName` might return NULL:

1. nodename is NULL (`kSCStatusInvalidArgument`);
2. nodename is empty (`kSCStatusInvalidArgument`); or
3. memory allocation problems (does not set a `kSCStatusXxx`).

He also noted that the reachability APIs are in Darwin, and that the Darwin implementation is close to the implementation on both OS X and iOS. The code [SCNetworkReachability.c from Darwin](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/configd/configd-453.16/SystemConfiguration.fproj/SCNetworkReachability.c) seems to confirm his take that the above three reasons are the only ways in which `SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName` returns NULL.

I also learned that the [System Configuration Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SystemConfiguration_Utilities/Reference/reference.html) contains information about detecting and interpreting errors generated by calling `SCxxx` functions, specifically things like `SCError()` and `SCErrorString()`.

I deliberately caused a NULL return from `SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName` by passing "" and NULL as names and then tried `SCError` and `SCErrorString` (referenced from the System Configuration Reference) and lo and behold I did some meaningful extra information:

```
reachtest1[9274:11303] isReachableWithName: entry: name: ""
reachtest1[9274:11303] SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName returned NULL!
reachtest1[9274:11303] SCError: 1002 SCErrorString: Invalid argument

reachtest1[9274:11303] isReachableWithName: entry: name: (null)
reachtest1[9274:11303] SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName returned NULL!
reachtest1[9274:11303] SCError: 1002 SCErrorString: Invalid argument
```

This accounts for NULL getting returned from two of the three cases from the Darwin code.

There's also a way to get a `CFErrorRef` using `SCCopyLastError()` which might actually have even more info in it. In addition to the aforementioned System Configuration Reference, see the [CFError Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFErrorRef/Reference/reference.html).

Given all this I'd say the first two cases wouldn't be retry-able since passing a NULL or zero-length host name is a progam logic error. The third memory-related case might be retry-able.